# force drawing from ppa instead of universe

Tags: apt, ppa, kodi

I installed Kodi a while back on what was then Ubuntu 17.04 (I'm now on 17.10) using `apt install kodi`. I always noticed it came with a Kodi from Debian banner and that the release was behind at 17.3.

Now that 17.5 came out, fixing some bugs I was experiencing, I want to update. However `apt update && apt upgrade` do not yield a newer version yet.

In addition, I seem unable to update Kodi from the ppa. I already added it to sources.list, but everytime I remove and reinstall kodi, it will draw from universe (17.3) instead of the ppa. I tried pinning but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Edit: `apt-cache policy | grep xbmc` output:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy | grep xbmc
  50 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu artful/main i386 Packages
     release v=17.10,o=LP-PPA-team-xbmc,a=artful,n=artful,l=Kodi stable,c=main,b=i386
  50 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
     release v=17.10,o=LP-PPA-team-xbmc,a=artful,n=artful,l=Kodi stable,c=main,b=amd64
```

`apt-cache policy kodi` output:

```
$ apt-cache policy kodi
kodi:
  Installed: 2:17.3+dfsg1-3
  Candidate: 2:17.3+dfsg1-3
  Version table:
 *** 2:17.3+dfsg1-3 500
        500 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I had no idea who's in charge of updating the universe repos. Thought that was Debian/Canonical. What does packaging entail and how do I go about it? I'd love to help but don't have the know-how. Anyway removed the offending line lest kittens be killed.

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy kodi`, please.

Comment: added, seems to point to universe but unsure as to why.

Comment: Seems like the PPA doesn't offer a package named `kodi` for 17.10... which is indeed the case: https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=artful

Comment: ah thanks, I should've checked that. Is there a way to force it (using an Ubuntu 16 version)?

Comment: There should be a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for this PPA. Edit it and replace `artful` with `xenial`.

Comment: many thanks! will try that. The nightly currently works on artful too.